# Doctrine for PHP configuration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Hi, everyone!

I'm building a PHP site and I decided to go with Doctrine as DBAL and ORM. I'm a bit rusty on my PHP skills, so please help me understand one thing.

The way to configure Doctrine, as specified in their docs is to execute code like this:

```
if ($applicationMode == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
}

$config = new Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/lib/MyProject/Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setProxyDir('/path/to/myproject/lib/MyProject/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');

if ($applicationMode == "development") {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
} else {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
}

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => 'database.sqlite'
);
```

What I'm puzzled about is how should you execute this code. Is it something you put in a config.php file and include in each of your pages, basically executing this each time a page is processed? Or am I supposed to do this configuration once?

On a related note - please help me understand how setting cache to ArrayCache instead of APC cache helps me during development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

doctrine is a pretty hard choice if your PHP skills are rusty... Anyway...

You can create the connection and eventmanger once in a bootstrap file. Then you can pass the eventmanager instance to your class constructors or make it availably through a static registry (dirty dirty dirty) or ...

This is a good starting point (for orm 2.0):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html

The only reason for using ArrayCache in dev mode I can think of is, that you do not have to configure APC at that point and can focus on your coding. In production mode APC gives you the extra boost and is highly recommended.

Regards
Flo

Comment: By bootstrap file - do you mean a file that is included in each one of my pages? If not, when is this file loaded and how are objects created in it persisted between page loads?

Comment: A object cannot persist between page loads. Yo will have to create it on every request. And yes - if you want to implement a one file-per-page "pattern" you will have to include this bootstrap file every time.

Comment: I would highly encourage you to use a PHP Web Framework for your project though.

Comment: Sadly there are many to choose from... I would probably violate StackOverflows Q&A condtions by advancing an option ;) Symfony is a full-stack framework and very popular. Zend Framework is also popular but has a different approach. A google search provides you with an extensive list.